# See if values is related to ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I have two models, Major and Course like this:

```
class Major(models.Model):
    required_courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name='required_courses')

class Course(models.Model):
    # a bunch of fields...
```

I have several Majors (Computer Science, Psychology, etc.) where each of them contains a different set of `required_courses`. In my `views.py` I am getting the course like this `course = Course.objects.get(id=pk)`. Is there an elegant way to see if this particular class is in `required_courses` in any of my `Major` models?

Im trying to use `majors = Major.objects.all().values("required_courses")` but that just returns `<QuerySet [{'required_courses': 1}, {'required_courses': 2}, {'required_courses': 4}, {'required_courses': 5}]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Recommended reading](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

The majors that are belonging to this course are in the related set:

```py
course = Course.objects.get(id=pk)
print(course.major_set.all())
```

However, you've misnamed it to "required_courses". The "related name" is the name of the field that Django create for the **other** model.

```py
course = Course.objects.get(id=pk)
print(course.required_courses.all())
```

You see now how confusing that is, so it's better to do this:

```py
class Major(models.Model):
    required_courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, 
        related_name='required_by_majors')

class Course(models.Model):
    # a bunch of fields...

course = Course.objects.get(id=pk)
print(course.required_by_majors.all())
```

Comment: That seems to return which major this class is a required course in. So I guess that if majors returns something, then this list is a major required course, and if nothing is returned, then this course is not part of a major. I guess that works thank you!